# Paid for tickets, but didn't receive the tickets. What should I do?

Tags: tickets, money, refunds

I tried to buy a flight ticket on [trip.ru](http://www.trip.ru/). I went  through all the steps, I filled all the forms correctly, my bank account was charged, and then instead of showing the page with the confirmation text, the site tried to get the same money one more time. They say if all went well I should receive my tickets by email.

But I haven't received any email, on my account of [trip.ru](http://www.trip.ru/)  there is no booked ticket, but I paid for the ticket. Yesterday I contacted them, and they said "something went wrong, and the money is blocked you should wait (they don't know how long)". What should I do? They don't answer my emails or phone calls today.

Comment: There is no such an organization to contact with this problem ?

Comment: If this was a credit card contest the charge, otherwise talk to your bank and get the police involved

Comment: What country are you in?

Comment: @Michael I'm in Armenia

Comment: They called me and said the money will be back in 17 days

Comment: So I lost my ticket, my nerves, my time, and my money (by the way it is more than the price the site provided me before purchasing) is blocked for several days (the bank said 17 days) due to their services. I'll not recommend anyone to use their services (If there are any other users).

Comment: Is the amount only blocked or reserved (as you state in question text and comments) or have you actually been charged for the ticket (as you claim in the title and several places in the text)? Voting to close as unclear until you have clarified what the situation actually is.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo I don't care technical details. My bank account was charged, my money was sent, it's not on my account anymore. After a day they said it will be back in 17 days. What is unclear here ?

Comment: This is not a technical issue. If the amount is merely blocked or reserved, your account has not been charged, no money has been sent and the money is still in your account. Your bank does not allow you to *access* that money until the reservation times out, but it is still there. If there is only a pending reservation and no actual charge, your very best bet is probably just to wait the 17 days for the money to be released.

Answer (score 1):

Not too much you can do.  Two options:

1) Keep contacting them. Try email, phone and social media. Often I've found social media is pretty good for responses.

2) If you paid by credit card, let your bank know what has happened. You can often get the charges reversed and your money back.